# Multi-line string search

Tags: java, regex

Let's say the user provides a search query input:

`word1 word2 word3`

And the text that's being searched looks like:

```
Some text some text some text word1 \r\n (newline here)
word2      word3 some text some text some text.
```

Is there a way to turn the user's input into a regular expression and basically get an index of where the search query starts and ends, with dismaying the line breaks and multiple spaces?

Comment: Split the search query by space and join it with `\\s+` to build a search pattern.

Comment: Have a look at this Java RegEx HowTo - [Boundary Matchers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

Comment: How do you want the result to look, exactly?

Comment: @ykaganovich I want to get start-end indices of search query with all the symbols in between counted in. In this case for example: (30, 53)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in that way:

```
public static String regex = "//s+" +"((" + word1 + ")|(" + word2 + ")|(" + word3 + "))//s+"

public static void printMatches(String text, String regex) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
  // Check all occurrences
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end());
    System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag to match text spanning multiple lines.